# How to select all searches containing two specific results in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to find all searches that returned two results that have been tagged as pairs in another table.

I have two tables:

**Search_Results**

```
...
request_id          varchar(16)
result_id           bigint
...
```

Where `request_id` corresponds to a search request and `result_id` corresponds to one of the results displayed. There are usually 10-15 results associated with each request.

**Result_Pairs**

```
...
left_result_id   bigint
right_result_id  bigint
...
```

`left_result_id` and `right_result_id` are a pair of result id's which correspond to `result_id`s in the search results table.

I'm fairly new to SQL and I cant for the life of me figure out how to get all the `request_id`s for searches that returned both results from a result pair. Where should I start? As a caveat, Search_Results has ~33 Billion rows and Result_Pairs has about 4 Million rows, so performance will be a concern. Search_Results can and will be cut down a lot by restricting by date, but will still be millions of rows.

Comment: Fixed. I was doing some stupid stuff with copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but something like this maybe:

```
select *
from search_results sr
  join result_pairs rp on sr.result_id 
                          between rp.left_result_id and rp.right_result_id;
where search_date = date '2015-01-15'
```

You will definitely need an index on `search_results (result_id)` and one on `result_pairs (left_result_id, right_result_id)` (and of course on that date column)